# UTF-8 text format issue in gtk

Tags: c, utf-8, gtk, gtktextview

Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_buffer_emit_insert: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (text, len, NULL)' failed

The above error comes when I open the popup window containing GtkTextView but this not happen all the time sometimes no error shown and text appear as expected but when I recompile for other changes the error appear and no text appear in gtktextview but again if i recompile the error remove on its own.
I don't understand such strange behavior , I have already tried converting text into UTF-8 format but same thing happens , no change.

Copied from comment:

```
char buff[1024];
version_buf = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
messege = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer(version_buf);
sprintf(buff,"Some long string data");
length = strlen(buff);
buff[length] = '\0';
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(version_buf,buff,length);
```

Comment: Please show us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how you create the related widgets.

Comment: char buff[1024];
version_buf = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
 messege = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer(version_buf);
sprintf(buff,"Some long string data");
length = strlen(buff);
buff[length] = '\0';
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(version_buf,buff,length);
if i copy few lines into buff then it work fine but I am copying almost 14 lines but total char count is less than 1024

Comment: It might be more useful if you show us an example of text that does cause the error. And please put your code into the question. In comments it is varely readable.

Comment: code added in the question , and I am getting text from diffrent functions which present in different thread , I a doing the same thing in different popup window but text is just "NO USB DEVICE FOUND" may be that's why there I have no such issue .@Gerhardh

Comment: First of all, this is useless: `length = strlen(buff); buff[length] = '\0';` as there is already a nul-terminator at this position.

Comment: You mention different threads. You should not call GTK function from any thread other than your main thread that handles the UI. When I did this (changed labels or checked/unchecked menuitems) I also got some strange messages from GTK.

Comment: I am not calling GTK function from different thread , I am just getting data into char buffer from different function and I know calling gtk functions other then menu cause strange behavior but i have already handled all of them except this one @Gerhardh